# Unable to start JavaFX GUI located in another class

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to start a JavaFX GUI that's located in another class from the Main class. Here is my JavaFX GUI class:

```
public class JavaFXGUI extends Application{
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("TextManipulator.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle(i18n.getString("program_full_name"));
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

This class is almost exactly copied from Oracle's own tutorial and works perfectly when the method is in the main class, but now I've moved it, and when I call 
`JavaFXGUI.launch(JavaFXGUI.class, args)`
from the main method, everything compiles fine but I get the following error constantly repeating when I run:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.sun.javafx.logging.PulseLogger
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:456)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:431)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.lambda$runToolkit$363(QuantumToolkit.java:298)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit$$Lambda$70/950205023.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$null$45(GtkApplication.java:126)
at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication$$Lambda$66/331637932.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I would be glad to post more code if necessary, I'm just not sure what code would be helpful, so please comment if I'm missing something important. Thanks in advance!

Comment: A missing private API class might be an indication of some incompatible versions somewhere. What platform are you on (OS, JDK version), and do you have a classpath set anywhere?

Comment: @James_D, I was running OpenJDK, and switching the SDK to regular JDK fixed the issue. If you formulate your comment as an answer, I will gladly mark it as the accepted answer. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that in my case, the problem was caused by my using OpenJDK rather than the Oracle one. Some other things to check are the Java version, the language level, and like in my case, making sure that the features you are trying to use are available in the JRE/JDK you are using.